# Making a more reactive model

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, model, trend

I am working on a model to predict quarterly values. I am running into an issue where my back data has extreme trends and my model (I am using a Holt-Winters model) seems to be taking these old values into account too much and thus my forecast has larger trends than I expect. Attached is an image with the values I am using in my model. You can see that the most recent trends are very small and I would expect future trends (values in yellow are my forecasts) to be more like this. Does anyone have a recommendation on how to handle this?

[image]

Comment: I am not too familiar with Holt-Winters but I understand that it uses exponentially declining weights the farther back an observation occurred. It sounds like that puts still too high of a weight on the old observations for you. Why not try an ARMA model using the classical Box-Jenkins approach. MA models of small order have very short memory. AR models' memory depends on the order and the coefficients on the lags but you may well end up with a model that is less reliant on those distant, anomalous observations that you brought up than your Holt-Winters model.

Comment: Use a damped Holt-Winters instead of regular Holt-Winters